# Why is shap.plots.bar() not working for me?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, feature-selection, shap, interpretation

I computed several shap values for my Neural Net and wanted to plot them as a bar plot that only shows the top 10 most important features as bars and sums up the importance of the rest in another bar.

As far as I understood, this should be possible using `shap.plots.bar()`.

However, whenever I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: You must pass an Explanation object, Cohorts object, or dictionary to bar plot!
```

Next thing I did, was to try using `shap.summary_plot( ..., plot_type="bar")` since that is another way of displaying shap values in a bar chart. This indeed worked for me, however this does not sum up features in one bar.

So my question is, what did I do wrong while using `shap.plots.bar()` or what can I do to get `shap.summary_plot( ..., plot_type="bar")` to sum up features in one bar?

Here is my code:

```
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model=agent.policy.predict, data=state_df, link="identity")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X = state_df.iloc[0:35,:])

shap.summary_plot(shap_values = shap_values[0],features = state_df.iloc[0:35,:], plot_type="bar")
shap.plots.bar(shap_values[0], max_display=10)
```

Note that my background data set has 35 samples and that I have 160 inputs and 8 outputs, so the shape of my inputs `state_df` is `(35, 160)` and of my outputs `action_df` is `(35, 8)`. Also whithin that code I am trying to display the shap values for the first output which is why I am using `shap_values[0]`.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue. using shap.plot_summary(..., plot_type="bar") works for me -

```
x = np.array(x_train[sample_indices], dtype=np.float32)
x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x).to(DEVICE)
e = shap.DeepExplainer(model, x_tensor)

shap_values = e.shap_values(x_tensor)

shap.summary_plot(
    shap_values, features=x_samples, feature_names=x_cols, plot_type="bar", max_display=30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. You can resolve this with the following:

```
X = state_df.iloc[0:35,:]
shap_values = explainer(X)
```